# Is it common to change scheduling policy?

Tags: c, unix, scheduler

I am getting extremely pissed off by a signal-safety problem that is tough to solve. Maybe it would be possible with the default scheduler, but the problem would vanish if I simply used a real-time scheduling policy such as FIFO so that I don't need to take into account the problem of my thread being preempted where I really don't want it to. Is it common in C programming to just pick what scheduling policy fits best and works the best, or should I rather try to solve the problem differently?

#### Warning

The question is about **using scheduling policy to your advantage in C language**. Please refrain from asking to describe the signal-safety problem I am having, or implying a XY problem, or asking to provide any code sample.

Comment: Ok, let me put it this way.... if choosing a different scheduling policy makes your app 'work', how will you feel confident that it will still 'work' in a a different process/thread environment, on faster/slower hardware or on systems with different core count?   You will not, and tweaking scheduler policies should only be undertaken as an attempt to improve performance, not to 'fix' critical bugs:(

Comment: I mean, how you got to this place is unclear - I suspect that your top-level design is just borken.

Comment: I never said it won't work if I don't change the scheduling policy. I said it would make my life easier changing the policy than doing anything else. Besides, there are no "critical bugs" to fix. There are only problems to solve, and often problems can be solved in multiple ways.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it common in C programming to just pick what scheduling policy fits best and works the best,…

No, it is not common. Scheduling policy is a matter for the operating system and the system’s owners, not for a programming language or a programmer writing in a particular programming language.

> … or should I rather try to solve the problem differently?

Yes. Generally, if you program does not work with any scheduling policy, your program does not work. A program (or application or collection of programs) that does not work with some particular scheduling policy generally is a broken program unless its specification specifically says it may rely on a particular scheduling behavior.

Comment: "Scheduling policy is a matter for the operating system and the system’s owners" I would argue. Matter of an operating system should rather be to treat all threads as best as it can to prevent starvation but also maximise throughput. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)): "In practice, these goals often conflict" - and I think it should rather be up to a programmer to pick what is best for their work. If it takes a scheduling policy to make my program faster and safer, I wouldn't mind sarcrifising the title of "brokeness" (FIFO is supported by nearly all sys).

Comment: "Generally, if you program does not work with any scheduling policy, your program does not work" Some time ago on my Windows 10 I ran GTA 4 and then via task manager I made it have a real-time scheduling policy (don't know if the default is FIFO or RR). It instantly crashed. I don't know if it sarcrifised the ability to do so for other technical reasons, or because "it is a broken program". Maybe FIFO did not exist in the Windows kernel back in 2009 and prior. But in case the first, then I would argue with this statement as well.

Comment: Re “Matter of an operating system should rather be…” That is an argument about what policy should be. It is not an argument about **who** should set the policy.

Comment: Setting a policy for a system vs a single thread is a difference though. I don't mean to modify the scheduling policy of all processes, but just of one thread.